# Updating a dictionary in pickle

Tags: python

I have dictionary inside a pickle file and i am trying to update the dictionary with a new key-value pair but however, i ran into an error `"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"`. upon googling the error, i noticed people suggesting to use `deep copy()` . question -> the dictionary data which i am trying to update inside pickle. So, do i need to deep copy the pickle and read copied version and update it ?

Thanks

code:

```
with open('cache.pickle', 'rb') as file:   ##### loading the pickle file
    currentCache = pickle.load(file)
    for key1, value1 in allIssuesCommentTimestamp.items():
        for key2, value2 in currentCache.items():
            allIssuesCommentTimestamp_date = time.strptime(value1.split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            currentCache_date = time.strptime(value2.split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            if (key1 == key2 and allIssuesCommentTimestamp_date > currentCache_date):
                currentCache[key2] = allIssuesCommentTimestamp.get(key1)
                updatedIssuekeys.append(key2)
            elif (key1 not in currentCache ):
                currentCache[key1] = allIssuesCommentTimestamp.get(key1)

with open('cache.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(currentCache, file)
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: You can't loop over `currentCache` and update it within that same loop.

Comment: Can i please know the best way to do it .

Comment: It seems you want to update `currentCache` using `allIssuesCommentTimestamp`. The way to do it is `currentCache.update(allIssuesCommentTimestamp)`. There is no need for the two loops.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pickle, this is just basic dictionary operations.

Comment: Can you describe in words what your code is supposed to be doing? The nested loop here doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with pickle. You can't update a dictionary/list while you are looping over it. For obvious reasons this could create various problems or infinite appends:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
for i in x:
    x.append(i)
```

Python will allow you to modify a dictionary/list you are looping over, if you don't change the size. However, if you add a new key to a dictionary, then the size changes while it is looping and that creates a probably (in theory that would change the number of loops it was going to do while in the middle of looping). To get around this, you need only loop over a copy. If your dictionary is simple (shallow) only containing direct objects like strings, numbers, etc., the dict built-in comes with a copy function already:

```
d = dict(a=1,b=2)
for k,v in d.copy().items():
    if k=='a':
        d['c'] = 7
```

If your dictionary has more complex keys/values (like lists of lists of strings or something that will be modified mid-loop), then you need to recursively copy all the objects in the dictionary. This can be done with the "deepcopy" function.

```
from copy import deepcopy
d = dict(l=dict(a=1,b=3),z=4)
e = deepcopy(d)
```

Comment: thank you.. since i am loading the pickle file into "currentcache", i though it would affect pickle.